# Не выводится время во втором окне WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно вести статистику сколько я просидел в одном из окон и выводить её во второе, делается через переменную в отдельном классе и таймере в окне в котором нахожусь, при этом если выводить значение в основное окно время идёт а во втором нет(
КОД:

```
MainWindow:
 public MainWindow()
        private DateTime startTime;
        private TimeSpan elapsedTime;
        private statistica myOtherClass = new statistica();        
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

public TimeSpan TimeSpent { get; set; }
        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
            myOtherClass.AddTime(elapsedTime);
            timerLabel.Content = elapsedTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
                switch (e.Key)
                {
                    case Key.F1:
                    HelpPage help = new HelpPage();
                    help.TotalTime = myOtherClass.TotalTime;
                    help.Owner = this;
                    help.Show();
                    break;
                 }

class statistica:
 public TimeSpan totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        public TimeSpan TotalTime
        {
            get { return totalTime; }
        }

        public void AddTime(TimeSpan timeToAdd)
        {
            totalTime += timeToAdd;
            
        }

HelpPage(второе окно):
 public HelpPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lbm.Content = "Переход на главную был выполнен " + statistica.Main + " раз." + " Время проведено " + TotalTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); ;
        }

public TimeSpan TotalTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: Почитать MVVM и про привязки данных

Comment: Чем в этой строке `lbm.Content = "Переход на главную был выполнен " + statistica.Main` является `statistica`? Как он туда попадает? Где создается?